# Show 2 languages at the same time in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, internationalization

friends.

I'm new to Flutter and ran into a problem. I found good i18n solution for supporting many locales via arb files. But can't find good way to show 2 texts in different locales at the same time in application. Left column would be in Primary language and right column - in Secondary.

Do you know standard ways to solve this problem or I need to implement everything from scratch?

Stupid solution is to implement it via html files with tables for both languages. The growth in the number of languages will increase the number of these files in an exponential order.

Thanks!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441212/flutter-multi-lingual-application-how-to-override-the-locale

Answer (score 0):

you can try from following repo

https://github.com/mkobuolys/flutter-code-generation

Comment: Thanks for help! I will check if it will help